# Quelle est la méthode correcte pour reformuler des phrases à partir de références dans ma thèse, mon rapport, etc. ?

Tags: expressions, formulation

Je suis en cours d'écriture de ma thèse de doctorat. Les deux premiers chapitres sont généralement des chapitres de rappel. Ils sont basés sur des articles et thèses de chercheurs et doctorants. Ma question : dans un article original nous trouvons beaucoup d'expressions comme: **nous proposons, nous négligeons, nous trouvons, on peut, nous considérons, etc.**

Par exemple l'expression suivante :

> **Nous négligeons la contribution capillaire et supposons que...**

Par exemple si je veux parler dans ma thèse que l'auteur de ce article a dit : **nous négligeons la contribution capillaire et supposons que....**, dans ma thèse j'avais toujours l'habitude d'écrire :

> **On néglige la contribution capillaire et on suppose que....**, et je pense que c'est faux.

Quelles sont les expressions les plus utilisées ?

Exemple : [Nom d'auteurs] proposent que la contribution capillaire soit négligée et supposent que...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En effet, je partage votre observation, la première version proposée « On néglige la contribution capillaire et on suppose que... » ne me semble pas adéquate puisqu'elle revient à reprendre ce fait à votre compte, alors que vous vous contentez d'y faire référence. Puisque vous parlez des choix faits par l'autre auteur dans son article, je pense que c'est ainsi qu'il faut le présenter.

> Dans son article, [Nom d'auteur] a choisi de négliger la contribution
>   capillaire et de supposer que...

Attention que cette tournure (avec le verbe « choisir ») ne s'applique pas forcément à tous les verbes introductifs rencontrés. Si dans un article, on lit « On observe que... », il suffira d'être direct et de dire « Dans son article, [Nom d'auteur] a observé que... ».

En revanche, dans le cas de « négliger », utiliser la même formule directe « [Nom d'auteur] a négligé » sera incorrect, car cela reviendrait à signaler une lacune dans l'article en question, alors que c'était en fait assumé par l'auteur.

Comment: Je pense qu'on ne peut écrire _[Nom d'auteur] a choisi de..._ uniquement si l'auteur indique explicitement qu'il s'agit d'un choix de sa part. La formule _dans son article [Nom d'auteur] néglige la contribution capillaire..._ me semble préférable.